# No ability to add rows in datagrid using EF + WCF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, datagrid, ado.net

When using Entity Framework for Accessing Database and modifying it I have everything OK. However when trying to modify (add records) to DB using EF+WCF, I can retrieve table contents in Datagrid, but I cannot add rows, I believe that I have incorrect GetAll method realization:

```
public List<blog> GetAll()
{
    return db.blogs.ToList();
}
```

IService1.cs file is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFSRV
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        int AddBlog(blog b);

        [OperationContract]
        List<blog> GetAll();

        ///[OperationContract]
        ///  void DeleteBlog(BlogService b);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }


    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
    // You can add XSD files into the project. After building the project, you can directly use the data types defined there, with the namespace "WCFSRV.ContractType".
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the call of the method upon Window Initialization:

```
private void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
        DG1.ItemsSource = scli.GetAll();
}
```

This is what I get as the result:

[image]

So the question is how can I make this Datagrid to resolve rows adding? (Surely property Canuseraddrows is set to true)

Thanks.

Added xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataBaseP" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="DataBaseP.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="700" Loaded="Window_Loaded" Initialized="Window_Initialized">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="blogViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type local:blog}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource blogViewSource}">

    <DataGrid x:Name="DG1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Margin="10,10,208,96" ItemsSource="{Binding}" EnableRowVirtualization="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="blogIDColumn" Width="SizeToHeader" Header="Blog ID" Binding="{Binding BlogID}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="authorColumn" Width="SizeToCells" Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="bsubjectColumn" Width="SizeToCells" Header="bsubject" Binding="{Binding bsubject}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="tagColumn" Width="SizeToCells" Header="Tag" Binding="{Binding Tag}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="AddBtn" Content="ADD/MODIFY" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="510,56,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129" Height="44" Click="AddBtn_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: take a look at mvvm and binding, then you dont have to think about "How can i add a Row to my DataGrid". then you jsut add the new rows to your Collection in your Viewmodel. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I suppose you've misunderstood me. THere is no problem in adding rows in code.
However, after running the application, I need to provide user with the ability to add rows through Datagrid, and this is the problem. So until I am using Entity Framework withou WCF - everything is fine: after clicking on the last filled row, the new empty row is created below. However once I am trying to realize the same through WCF, it is not working.

Comment: Post your code showing when and how `AddBlog` gets called.

Comment: @jstreet, I didn't call it yet, since I suppose that datagrid should give me ability to add row to itself before transferring the row to database.

Comment: You really need to follow advice you've already been given about looking into MVVM, otherwise this could be a long conversation leading to nowhere. Perhaps you _got away_ with it doing it the way you're doing, but if you're now going to throw WCF in the mix, then you need to start doing things the correct way, following established patterns.

Comment: @jstreet, thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify what do you exactly mean "looking into MVVM"? I have added .xaml code to my original post, please let me know if I need to add something more to help you troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Look here for an introduction: [The MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

Comment: @jstreet, thank you for the information:)